# windows mobile 6.1 autostart application after clean boot

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, boot

I have an c# application that I am installing during cleanboot on a windows mobile 6.1 device.  It installs correctly, however, I need to get it to autostart after cleanboot.

I always have to warmboot the handheld after cleanboot to make it start.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

I asume, you are using a CAB file to install your C# app during cleanboot.

You may use a setup.dll inside the cab to start your app after the cab files have been installed using the DLL's Install_Exit function call (setupdll sample for example here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7724/Creating-Pocket-PC-Application-Setup-Packages-Usin). But MS states you cannot rely on calling files of the cab install itself.

Another approach would be a seond cab that is installed after your C# app install and just calls your app, even using a setup dll.

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158796.aspx for howto pack several cabs into one install.

The problem with cleanboot installers and AutoStart is, that the OS already has run \Windows\StartUp and also other autostarts when the cab has been installed. Therefor you normally need a reboot that then executes your app using StartUp (or HKLM\Init).

You may also use a scripting engine to install the cab and then launch your installed app. For example use MortScript, which supports being used as "AutoStart.exe" inside SD Card\2577 or similar dir (Volume name\2577). The the script can call wceload.exe  to install your app and afterwards start the executable of the installed app. Something like using a batch.

As this is an Intermec install, you can use \Flash File Store\UserAutoInstall_sstransferagent.xml to automate the install and launch of the app.

For example: Your cab is at \Flash File Store\MyInstall\MyCab.cab and installs MyApp.exe to \Program Files\MyApp:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Devices>
    <Device Type="" Family="" Model="" Boot="">
        <Files SrcDir="\Flash File Store\UserAutoInstall">
            <File SrcName="" 
               DestName="wceload.exe" 
               DestDir="\Windows" 
               Run="true" 
               CmdLine='"\Flash File Store\MyInstall\MyCab.cab" /silent /verifyconfig /nodelete' 
            />
        <File SrcName="" 
               DestName="MyApp.exe" 
               DestDir="\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe" 
               Run="NoWait" 
               CmdLine='' 
            />
        </Files>
   </Device>
</Devices>
```

regards